# Days time sumation

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, t-sql

These are my table field

```
 AtdId  MCId    AtdDate              CheckIn                CheckOut            Status
    675 7   2013-10-03  2013-10-03 16:42:49.307         2013-10-03 16:43:10.317 0#0#56
    676 7   2013-10-03  2013-10-03 16:46:28.730         2013-10-03 16:46:35.780 0#0#7
    677 7   2013-10-03  2013-10-03 16:49:33.190     2013-10-03 16:49:35.140 0#0#2
    678 7   2013-10-03  2013-10-03 16:49:36.913         2013-10-03 16:49:38.377 0#0#2
    679 7   2013-10-03  2013-10-03 16:49:39.397     2013-10-03 16:49:40.023 0#0#1
    680 7   2013-10-03  2013-10-03 16:49:41.043         2013-10-03 16:49:41.703 0#0#0
    681 7   2013-10-03  2013-10-03 16:49:43.307         2013-10-03 16:49:45.063 0#0#2
    682 7   2013-10-03  2013-10-03 16:50:33.657         2013-10-03 16:50:45.783 0#0#12
    683 7   2013-10-03  2013-10-03 16:51:35.007         2013-10-03 16:52:42.877 0#1#7
```

Status field 0#0#0 is hour#minute#second. How can I sum of daily hour minute and second to show total duration for date wise?
Status is varchar in db and i am using MSSQL.

Comment: What is the RDBMS you are using? What is the data type of the field `status`? What is the desired results of the sample data you provide?

Comment: Please, can you show the attempts you have made so far? Just showing the inputs and telling "make this work for me" is not how questions are expected to be asked here.

Comment: Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.** Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: Do you want SUM the time in Status? Is that same as SUM(DATEDIFF(second,CheckIn, CheckOut)?

Comment: Status is difference of Check In and check Out in hour#minute#second

Comment: Why you cant use EricZ's sugegstion? any issues of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still feel it's a better idea to SUM from CheckIn and CheckOut column. However, if you want SUM from Status, here is one way to do it.

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT 
    *,
    PARSENAME(REPLACE(Status,'#','.'), 1) AS StatusSecond,
    PARSENAME(REPLACE(Status,'#','.'),2) AS StatusMinute,
    PARSENAME(REPLACE(Status,'#','.'),3) AS StatusHour
  FROM tbl
)
SELECT [AtdDate], SUM(StatusHour*60*60 +  StatusMinute * 60 + StatusSecond) AS TotalTimeInSecond
FROM cte  
GROUP BY [AtdDate]
ORDER BY [AtdDate]
```

***[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/af11c/7)***

**Edit:**

To filter on Current day/week/month, you can add the following condition in above query.

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(week,AtdDate,GETDATE()) = 0 
-- You can change week to Day or Month
```

More Deails, Please see [DATEDIFF](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)

Comment: thanks EricZ but I only want totalsecond for current date. How could i do this?

Comment: Add "WHERE CAST(AtdDate AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)"

Comment: thanks EricZEeEeEeEe . . . :)

Comment: EricZ:if I want for current week and current month total time what sholud I do?